# Unrecognized Selector for NSNull isCString

Tags: xcode

I am experiencing unrecognized selector for this:

`-[NSNull _isCString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

The given log crashes my app. What are the possible causes of this error? Can anyone give some ideas? Any response will be very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Actually, I just want to edit a row from a table view controller. I have noticed that when I click the EDIT at the navigation bar of my table view controller, the rows 0, 2 and 4 gets the error but the rows 1 and 3 doesn't.

```
2014-08-13 11:39:27.531 boysenios[5253:60b] -[NSNull _isCString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2068068
2014-08-13 11:39:27.535 boysenios[5253:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull _isCString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2068068'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f1c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c9b8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01fb9243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01f0c50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01f0c0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Foundation                          0x018cc986 -[NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 317
    6   Foundation                          0x018cc815 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:] + 384
    7   UIFoundation                        0x03e86774 __71-[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]_block_invoke + 68
    8   UIFoundation                        0x03e866af -[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:] + 121
    9   Foundation                          0x018f6f76 -[NSMutableAttributedString setAttributedString:] + 90
    10  UIKit                               0x01065c6c __32-[UITextView setAttributedText:]_block_invoke + 43
    11  UIFoundation                        0x03e84211 -[NSTextStorage coordinateEditing:] + 48
    12  UIKit                               0x010658cb -[UITextView setAttributedText:] + 254
    13  UIKit                               0x01069eb5 -[UITextView setText:] + 149
    14  boysenios                           0x000233c6 -[ProjectFormTableViewController resetView] + 3873
    15  boysenios                           0x00022494 -[ProjectFormTableViewController setViewToEdit:] + 61
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cad880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    17  UIKit                               0x0095d3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    18  UIKit                               0x00c4a8df -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cad880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    20  UIKit                               0x0095d3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    21  UIKit                               0x0095d345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    22  UIKit                               0x00a5ebd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    23  UIKit                               0x00a5efc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    24  UIKit                               0x00a5e243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    25  UIKit                               0x0099cddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    26  UIKit                               0x0099d9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    27  UIKit                               0x0096f5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    28  UIKit                               0x00959353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x01ea577f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01ea510b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01ec21ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01ec19d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01ec17eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x033345ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x0333442b GSEventRun + 104
    36  UIKit                               0x0095bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    37  boysenios                           0x00027f83 main + 94
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x02fcd701 start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Posting more code would help, but my guess is that you are calling a method (selector) on a non object.

Comment: Very simple.  You have a NSNull object.  It does not recognize the method `_isCString`.  Likely you got the NSNull in a JSON string, so you need to add logic to check if that pointer is an NSNull:  `if (myPointer == [NSNull null]) ...`

Comment: And post the code and the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSNull` is a class that class does not implement `_isCString`, hence the unrecognized selector error. Objective-C usually uses `nil` to represent a 0 or a null pointer value. However, standard containers like `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` cannot hold nil values, so you occasionally see `[NSNull null]` used instead.

It's basically convention in your code that determines whether you check for `myVal == [NSNull null]` or `myVal == nil`.

Based on the trace you posted, it appears you need to do a `myVal == [NSNull null]` check somewhere.

Comment: I'd add that based on line 13 in the stack trace, I'd say it's setting some `UITextView`'s `.text`  property to nil:  `13  UIKit 0x01069eb5 -[UITextView setText:] + 149`

Comment: Could you please set some example Mr. Mike S what did you add based in line 13 of the stack trace? I still get the error of my app.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally resolve the issue. :)